# Inner join usage issue in sql

Tags: sql, inner-join

Could you please tell me if the following is acceptable in SQL language-

Can I write a join statement to JOIN 2 tables ON condition, when the condition is the equality of 2 attributes with different names. For example is it valid to write

```
FROM A join B ON A.c = B.d
```

If the a.c and b.d attributes contain values of the same type and are logically the same things. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sure. Couldn't you have just tried it and gotten your answer? In future SQL-related questions, please tag your [RDBMS (MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server, etc)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system)

Comment: Yes - welcome to SQL!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is standard SQL.  This is an answer in order to notate the valid forms of `Inner join` operations in SQL along with what is generally disfavoured and why.

The first are the old style "implicit cross join and filter" approach.  In this way you would write:

```
SELECT *
  FROM a, b
 WHERE a.c=b.c
```

This is generally disfavoured because separating the join condition and the join itself makes it harder to troubleshoot the query, harder to read, and therefore harder to maintain.  The next two equivalent approaches are what you are using:

```
SELECT *
  FROM a
  JOIN b ON a.c = b.c
```

You can also use `INNER JOIN` instead of `JOIN`:

```
    SELECT *
      FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON a.c = b.c
```

Now there is another approach here which also works (but runs into issues in some cases), which is that since you are using the same query you can use the `using` keyword:

```
SELECT *
  FROM a
  JOIN b USING (c);
```

Finally there is the natural join, assuming that c which is the same as `USING` except that it picks all columns with the same name:

```
      SELECT *
        FROM a
NATURAL JOIN b;
```

Usually we use `ON` because it is unambiguous and puts the join conditions in the same part of the query as the join itself, making for easier maintenance.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped.